I2C LOW-level output voltage
I've been confused about electrical characteristics table in I2C specification (Table 10)
What are differences between LOW-level input voltage and LOW-level output voltage ?
As an example if I have I2C device which has internal MOSFET at it's SDA/SCL pin and maximum voltage drop on it should be 0.4V when SDA/SCL line pulled low, is that correct? So used MOSFET in I2C peripheral should always support this characteristic independently of manufacturers?


The Low-level input voltage is the maximum voltage that is guaranteed to be recognized as a Low level.
The Low-level Output voltage is the maximum voltage that will be output for a Low under the specified conditions.
The Low level input voltage spec will always be higher than the Low level output voltage to ensure that when a part outputs a Low that signal will be recognized as a Low.

It has nothing to do with I2C.
All digital logic have a valid input range and valid output range, and the valid output range must be larger than the valid input range for proper operation.
For I2C it means that when pulling low, your device must pull below 0.4V while sinking 3mA. Your device is allowed to be stronger, i.e. voltage can be near 0V while sinking more current, but a weaker device does not fit within I2C specs.
And since output must pull below 0.4V, the input must detect up to 0.3×Vdd as logic low properly, a fundamental property of digital logic that valid output levels must be better than valid input levels.
